# Access issue on App_data mdf file of website

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf, service, iis-7.5

I am stuck into the deployment of website from installshield limited edition where I have a database file in the `App_Data` folder along with this I have one scheduler functionality into website, for this I have created a Windows service and calling though the WCF call.

Now I am accessing the `.mdf` file from the website as well as WCF with the edmx.

But the problem is once I deploy the website at IIS and if I start the Windows service manually from that point on, I am getting the access issue such as

> Cannot open database "C:\INETPUB\WWWROOT\XYZWEBSITE\APP_DATA\XYZ.MDF" requested by the login. The login failed.
>   Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool'.

If I stop the Windows service then it works, and vice versa.

Anyone gone through this situation and got any ways to get the work done?

Waiting for reply

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you need to access a SQL Server database (that's what a `.mdf` file really is) from **multiple** places, then you should **put the database ON THE server** instead of fiddling around with files..... just put the database on a SQL Server instance, and access it from both your Windows service as well as your web app using the logical database name - and let SQL Server handle all the file-fiddling details for you .....

Comment: @marc_s thanks for reply but prob is we don't want to install the sql server on a client side.and we are creating a setup from installshield limited edition of website which will automatically setup into the iis server.

Comment: If you want to use the `.mdf` file - you **have to** install at least SQL Server Express .....